# ReactJS - Use this inside a Listener from Google Map

Tags: reactjs

I use Google Map in pure JS (to use easily Clusters & Drawings tools).

I just face this problem, I want to use my state inside a listener :

```
_handleGoogleMapApi = async (map, google) => {
    
   // ......

    google.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type !== google.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            console.log(this);
            const shapesCount = this.state.shapes.length;
            this.state.shapes.push({shapesCount: e})
        }
    }, this);

   // ......
```

And I have this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'shapes' of undefined

I've added the :

```
}, this);
```

At the end, but same result. I checked, the `this` is related to Google Map, not my react component.

How can I access the state inside this listener ?

Answer (score 0):

To use the state inside your google maps event listener, you need to use the ES6 [arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp). It should look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (e) => {
  if (event.type !== 'marker') {
    console.log(this.state.shapes.length)
  }
}
```

Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawing-manager-listener-g48hsa?file=App.js).